# List Default View Filtered

Tags: 2013, list-view

When I add a list to a page, I see the default view. When I set some filters and change the view and set it as default view, this new default view is only shown when you open the direct link to the list. I know that I can change the default view of a list on a page and after saving it, it is permantly displayed on the page so that is actually fine. However via the modiy view, one can only set 3 filters without using any code. However, more filters can be applied, when you filter on the shown list directly using the drop down menu on each column name. However, when ich save this view it is as described above only visible when I use the direct link to the page.

So my question is, how can I display a saved list view on the page rather than on the direct link?

Comment: I use SharePoint 2013 and I have no SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - it works via edit web part and there you can change the default view. once done it is displayed on the page and not only at the specific web url address